# Pandas - Update column with numbers / string extracted by using regex only on rows retrieved based on specific conditions

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean data from a file. I have done a partial clean and the data looks like this.

[image]

The `Price` column still needs to be cleaned and updated into other columns. This is what I want to do

```
Str '80 per piece' =>

80 -> 'Price' column
'piece' -> 'Unit' column

Str '110 per pack' =>
110 -> 'Price' column
'pack' -> 'Unit' column
```

I created a mask to retrieve the rows I need and then used regex to extract non-digits. I find that it affects all the rows. When I try to use only the rows retrieved by the mask - I get an error.

**How to ensure only the column in the conditionally retrieved rows is affected ?**

This is my code - Incorrect output without using mask on both sides.

[image]

But if I try this using the mask - I get this error

[image]

Comment: You must have meant to use `t[mask]['Price'].str.replace(r'\D+', '')`

Comment: @Wiktor - No, the string is to populate both Price and Unit. I am displaying the code for Unit. The code for Price also behaves in the same way. All rows get affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can `extract` with named groups and then `update`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Unit":["gm", np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   "Price":["40","80 per piece", "110 per pack"]})

  Unit         Price
0   gm            40
1  NaN  80 per piece
2  NaN  110 per pack

s = df.loc[df["Unit"].isnull(),"Price"].str.extract("(?P<Price>\d+)\sper\s(?P<Unit>[A-Za-z]+)").dropna()

df.update(s)

print (df)

    Unit Price
0     gm    40
1  piece    80
2   pack   110
```

Comment: How to apply only to relevant rows using the conditional extract ? It does the extraction though.

Comment: You can specify the columns with `nan` on column `Unit`. See edited above @Vidya.

Comment: Oh thanks. That will work partially. There are rows with bad data in the price column which have '-' in the unit column.

Comment: I guess I should '-' with Nan or something and then try.